# Re-use fields in a content type

Tags: navigation

I have a content type with 4 different sections to it.  At the bottom of each section, there are 2 "Call to action" links.

These links all point to the same 2 urls.  I'd like to be able to set up 2 fields of the type "link" and then re-use those fields 4 times, instead of having to set up 8 links.

Is this possible?

Is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: use multivalue link field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these sections are text or similar, you can create [field collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) that enclose other fields.

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.